# Various errors while trying to use variables as parameters

Tags: java, methods, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm writing a program to take an input of a text file containing a 50 by 50 block of three different characters: # , * and / , and colour each pixel of an ouput PNG file in accordance with each symbol so that there is a colour associated with each of the characters. However, I am experiencing several syntax errors related to passing variables as parameters. These Syntax errors are listed below:

```
Syntax error on token ",", < expected [21 , 59]
Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ArrayType [22,5]
Syntax error, insert ">" to complete ReferenceType1 [22,5]
Syntax error on token ",", delete this token [88, 53]
Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameter [88,69]
image_width cannot be resolved to a variable [90, 40]
image_height cannot be resolved to a variable [90, 53]
input_file_path cannot be resolved to a variable [92 , 59]
```

Could someone advise me on how to pass these parameters without error? Would be much appreciated.

Here is the program code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter; 

public class Lab_Week8_ImgFrmTxt_Part2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {  

    int image_width = 50;
    int image_height = 50;
    String output_file_path = ("image.png");
    String input_file_path = "superimage.txt";

    }

    public static BufferedImage imageFromText (image_width, image_height, input_file_path, output_file_path, 
    int r, int g, int b, char[][] characters) throws IOException{

        if(image_width <= 0 || image_height <= 0) {
            System.err.println("Width and Height have to be strictly positive!");
            return null;
        }

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage (image_width, image_height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        BufferedImage imagetowrite = imageFromText(image_width, image_height, input_file_path, output_file_path, r, g, b, characters); 
        File f = new File (output_file_path);
        ImageIO.write(imagetowrite, "png", f);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for (x = 0; x < image_width; x++)
        {
        for (y = 0; y < image_height; y++){

            if (characters[x][y] == ('#'))
            {r = 255;
            b = 0;
            g = 0;
            }

            else if (characters[x][y] == ('/'))
            {r = 0;
            b = 255;
            g = 0;
            }

            else if (characters[x][y] == ('*'))
            {r = 0;
            b = 0;
            g = 255;
            }
            setPixel(image, x, y, r, g, b); }
        }
        return image;
    }

    public static void setPixel(BufferedImage image, int x, int y, int r, int g, int b) {

        if(x < 0 || y < 0) {
            System.err.println("Coordinates (x, y) cannot be negative numbers!");
            return;
        }
        if(r < 0 || r > 255 || g < 0 || g > 255 || b < 0 || b > 255) {
            System.err.println("Colour values (r, g, b) have to be between 0 and 255!");
            return;
        }

        int a = 255; //alpha value
        /*
         * Write the different value of the pixel, i.e. the colours red, green, blue and alpha.
         * The different colour values are all stored into a single integer using byte operators.
         * a = x << y means write the value of x as bytes at the address y in the object a.
         * a = o1 | o2 means a will be composed by o1 and o2, where o1 and o2 are binary operators.
         * It is necessary to use this operator because the setRGB method of BufferedImage 
         * take only one integer that have to hold all the colour values for one given pixel.
         */
        int p = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;

        image.setRGB(x, y, p);
    }

    public static char[][] readTextImage(image_width, image_height, input_file_path) throws FileNotFoundException {  
        /* Create a 2-dimensional array of characters to store the data from the file */  
        char[][] characters = new char[image_width][image_height]; 

        Scanner reader = new Scanner (new FileInputStream(input_file_path));

        /* Set x and y variable at 0 to keep track of the coordinates */  
        int x = 0; 
        int y = 0;  
        /* While there is something to read in the file */  
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {   
            String s = reader.nextLine();  /* Grab the next line */   
            for (int i = 0; i < s.toCharArray().length; i++) {   /* For each character in the current line */    
                /* Get the current character (use s.toCharArray and the index i to access the right element */    
                char c = reader.next().charAt(0);
                /* Fill the 2-dimentional array of character with c at x and y coordinates */    
                characters [x][y] = c;
                /* Update the x coordinate */    
                x += 1;   }   
                /* Reset the x coordinate and update the y coordinate */   
                x = 0;   
                y += 1;  } 

        reader.close();  
        return characters; }   /* Close the scanner and return the 2-dimensional array */ 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the variable's type. Line 22 and 88, that fixes all the errors.

Follow this pattern when defining the parameters `<identifier> <variable_name>`

Comment: I have specified the variables' types in the main method. Do I then have to specify their type again when I pass them as a parameter? Thought this creates a second variable of the same name if I do that.

Comment: @Charlie You have to specify the type whenever you're defining a parameter. And you're working on different scopes, they can have the same name.
The issue here is the missing data type.
Give this a read https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods_param.asp

Comment: Ok, I've now specified the data type within the parameter like so: public static BufferedImage imageFromText (int image_width, int image_height, String input_file_path, String output_file_path, 
    int r, int g, int b, char [][] characters) throws IOException{

Comment: Now I'm being told that the variables in the main method are never used. I've put some print statements inside the methods to test whether the variables output anything and they are blank.